# Stream File to Client

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, telerik, filestream

I have this code to save an excel file to server from telerik

```
using (FileStream input = new FileStream(dirPath + FileName, FileMode.Create))
{
    formatProvider.Export(workbook, input);            
}
```

What I would like to do is stream the file to the client without saving it on the server first.

Comment: What is the type of `formatProvider`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what `formatProvider` is, but I'm assuming the second parameter takes a `Stream` so you can probably write it straight to the `Response.OutputStream` instead of a `FileStream`:

```
//Set some other headers like Content-Disposition
formatProvider.Export(workbook, Response.OutputStream);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are saving a workbook in server and then sending it to client for download. I'll use something like this

```
formatProvider.Export(workbook, Response.OutputStream);
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("attachment;filename=\"{0}\"", filename + extension));
Response.Flush();
```

`Response.Flush` method will flush the content of the output stream to client.